# Jquery: Ajax request looks synchronous, locking the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm having some issues with my Ajax call. I need to display a lot of data from json files, but this process is locking up the entire tab or browser.

I'm loading 2.5MB of words into a single div. When it runs properly asynchronous it should be working ok imho. Or is 2,5MB just too much for the browser to handle?

My goal is for the browser to remain responsive while loading. I can create a loading screen while the function is running, but that is of later issue.

Here's my code:

```
function returnWords() {
            var input2 = '', chr = '';
            for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
                input2 = String.fromCharCode(i);
                chr = input2.toLowerCase();
                console.log(chr);

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'words/words_' + chr + '.json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: true,
                    success: function(words) {
                        console.log(chr + ' done');
                    }
                });
                var w = "";
                w = words.join();
                var output = w.split(',').join('<br />');
                $('.result').append(output);
            } 
            console.log('done');
        };
```

Comment: Are you, by any chance, running this on every keypress in an input field?

Comment: in latest version of jquery there is no need to `async` attribute. Also 2.5M is really a big data

Comment: No, this is just a function that executes on the click of a button

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan, it also locks up without that attribute. I'm using  jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: Probably not related, but it looks like you're not creating a closure for `chr`.

Comment: Okay - that's a relief :p

Comment: I can't work out what this code would do. `words` is not available when you call `words.join()`.

Comment: @lonesomeday I see. I thought I'd put the words.join() function outside the success function, because that will surely cause things to lock up as it's inside the for loop. But that doesn't work either.

Comment: Try it with a smaller sample of words or without the for loop. I imagine that the browser is dying a bit with re-rendering big chunks 35 times.

Comment: @Forza it's still inside the `for` loop, though.

Comment: @Archer wow... that's a bit of a fail isn't it...

Comment: I don't know how to do it. It doesn't work within the for loop as well as out the for loop. I just want to load these files into the div one by one. Isn't there a way to achieve this dynamically?

Comment: You're firing 26 AJAX requests in quick succession, of course it will lag!

Comment: @RobH Sorry for pointing it out - I couldn't resist :)

Comment: I'll try make it a while loop and do i++ in the success function. But it still locks up

Comment: If I'm not wrong, then 2.5 MB are about 2,500,000 Bytes and assuming that each word has about 6 characters, then you have >400,000 words (assume ASCII encoding). Adding >800,000 DOM nodes to the document at once probably has some serious impact on performance, especially if you do this over and over again in the loop.

Comment: @Felix that's exactly what my issue is :) How can I prevent all these files from loading at once?

Comment: Couldn't `w = words.join(); var output = w.split(',').join('<br />');` be simplified to `var output = words.join('<br/>')`? The volume of data would still be a problem, but that could help a little.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not doing so many you'll get a *stack overflow*, this looks like it could more suitably be written as a recursion

```
function returnWords() {
    var w = [], output; // share these over each step
    function step(i) {
        var chr;
        if (i <= 90) { // more chrs to go
            chr = String.fromCharCode(i).toLowerCase();
            console.log(chr);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'words/words_' + chr + '.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (words) {
                    console.log(chr + ' done');
                    w = w.concat(words); // save for later
                    step(i + 1);
                }
            });
        } else {
            output = w.join().split(',').join('<br />');
            $('.result').append(output);
            console.log('done');
        }
    }
    step(65);
}
```

This code will only fire off one *REQUEST* at a time, each following the previous, until it reaches the end.

Comment: Ironically that I got a stack overflow in my question on this site :)

Comment: The effect is pretty much the same. It still locks up :(

Comment: Isn't the amount of data I'm trying to load just too large to handle?

Comment: what stage does this lock up at? I can use it on this website (with some minor adjustments) and it loops over each letter fine.

Comment: The console output shows each chr + 'done'. Also the final 'done' is shown. My guess is it locks up at the final stage of appending the output to the result div

Comment: @Forza the final `done` shouldn't show until after it has been appended. Are you sure that  you are not also performing a second action? Also, if the arrays of words are really huge, so the append is the cause, you might be better off appending them a couple hundred at a time with a few _ms_ break between each.. or you know, just as a single piece of text styled as a _pre_.

Comment: Doing it as a recursion lets you pace your code better, still.

Comment: Hi paul I have copied over your function exactly as you've written it. I've uploaded the files I'm working with so you can test for yourself: http://speedy.sh/aNCkG/words.zip (they are opensource anyway so that's no problem)

Comment: Very helpful to get a power outage while trying to fix something like this :)

Comment: I think I might go with your suggestion to append a couple of hundred at a time. That will at least keep the browser responsive

Comment: In case you wanna download the files, use this instead: http://www.sendspace.com/file/32ezau The other link wants you to install a download manager